# error al convertir archivo python a .exe No module named

Tags: python, python-3.x

Saludos estoy intentando convertir el codigo de python3.10 a un archivo.exe en windows 10, lo intento con PYINSTALLER: pyinstaller.exe --onefile aplicacion.py y me lanza este error: pero el programa funciona perfectamente desde la aplicacion de python.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego lo intengo con py2exe y me lanza este error al intentar ejecutarlo, el modulo reportlab lo utilizo para crear un archivo en PDF y funciona bien, no le falta ningun modulo:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aplicacion.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "reportlab\platypus\__init__.pyc", line 7, in <module>
  File "reportlab\platypus\flowables.pyc", line 32, in <module>
  File "reportlab\lib\styles.pyc", line 28, in <module>
  File "reportlab\rl_config.pyc", line 45, in <module>
  File "reportlab\rl_config.pyc", line 17, in _defaults_init
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'reportlab.rl_settings'
```

Me podrian ayudar con lo que esta pasado?

Answer (score 1):

La solucion solo era importar el modulo faltante, que por alguna razon necesitaba para crear el ejecutable, al final termine utilizando auto-py-to-exe que pedia este modulo, solo fue importarlo y listo.

```
import babel.numbers
```